# List streams available with Red5

Tags: java, flash, rtmp, red5, red5-recorder

I am developing an application with the red5 server. I would like to create a simple webservice that to be asked to return the names of streans (rtmp: // IP / canal / stream) available at that time.

My application is simple. The context also have the usual red5 server, sending and receiving video streans and would like to create something in JAVA to list the streans that are running / available at the time to be able to access them on a remote site with 1 or N streans by example.

I am having doubt in how to assemble the code snippet for the streans of red5, the rest is ready. Do you have any idea how to find it? I am having some difficulty in finding some examples and docs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of streams, first get your "scope" and then get the collection of child scopes. These children will be of "broadcast" type should they actually represent streams. This may be a little out-of-date, but you'll find an example on page 3 of this pdf: 
https://red5.googlecode.com/files/1827OS_04_1stDraft.pdf

Comment: Do you have an updated file of this pdf?  The link is broken I know it has been 2 years

Comment: Red5 Pro has sample code here for their version https://github.com/red5pro/red5pro-server-examples/blob/master/red5prolive/Red5ProLive/src/com/red5pro/live/Red5ProLive.java

Comment: Heres more links to the odt files https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7316897/red5/chapters/1827OS_02_1stDraft.odt https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7316897/red5/chapters/1827OS_04_1stDraft.odt https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7316897/red5/chapters/1827OS_06_1stDraft.odt

Comment: @PaulGregoire could you please update the shared free chapters

Comment: You should be able to grab them here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a434d5g63a4mn8a/AADRZArgQhEGBFvzrEA6QECEa?dl=0